# How to integrate spring security with custom authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am using third party authenticator, which is invoked when the application starts and shows login screen and after successful authentication, grants access to the application.

After successful authentication it forwards to a spring controller for user loading.

I would like to know how can i use spring security api for custom providers.

I want to call spring security api after the authentication is done and while the user details are being loaded etc to build up roles and GrantedAuthority etcs.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        //... load user profile from third party authenticator.
        return model;

    }
}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomAuthenticationProvider thirdPartyAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error.html");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(thirdPartyAuthenticationProvider);
    }

}
```

**Custom Provider**

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{



    @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)   throws AuthenticationException {
            // use the credentials to try to authenticate against the third party system
            if (authenticatedAgainstThirdPartySystem()) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
            } else {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Unable to auth against third party systems");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            /return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
        }

    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You load the authorities/roles in the AuthenticationProvider?

Comment: javadoc says that you should return a fully populated Authentication object (including granted authorities) if successful.

Comment: I am trying to load authorties/roles in the WelcomeController  controller (see above) after the authentication was success and it forwarded the request to /welcome

Comment: As mentioned you should prepare a full authentication object. What do you think happens if there are no roles and the redirect happens? You don't have access. You should do everything in your custom `AuthenticationProvider` and not your controller.